# On enter some text textbox only the Table should display

Tags: angularjs

Here when i enter some text in textbox then only the table should be display,or else table should not display.

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/15/

```
     <input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
       <table class="tftable" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
          <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
          <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
          <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
          <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
          <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
          <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
```

help me out in this Thanks

Comment: didnt get what u want...

Comment: Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/16/

Comment: dfsq when type text in textbox only the table should show. or else should hide

Answer (score 0):

You should add ngModel directive to input element and use this model with `ngShow/ngHide` directives on the table to control if it should be visible or not.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="text" />
<table class="tftable" border="0" ng-hide="text == 'boom'">
    /* ... */
</table>
```

in the example above the table will be hidden if the text entered is `boom`. You can use `ng-show` for reverse behavior.

One more issue. Make sure you the table is withing `ngApp` and `ngController` containers. I moved it in the demo.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/17/

Answer (score 0):

You need:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Add a ng-model to the input so and $scope, then use ng-show on the table.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input.text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
       <table class="tftable" border="0" ng-show="input.text.length > 0">
```